# Square root of an eigenvalue of linear map $T^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this question, not really sure where to start:

Show that if $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2 = T \circ T$, then either $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T.

Comment: Start with $T^2-\lambda^2 I=(T-\lambda I)(T+\lambda I)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $T\circ T - \lambda^2 \mathrm{Id} = (T - \lambda \mathrm{Id})\circ (T+\lambda\mathrm{Id})$. Call this map $F$.

Let $v\neq 0$ be a vector such that $F(v)=0$. Define $w:=(T+\lambda \mathrm{Id})(v)$.

Then either $w=0$, in which case $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ to the eigenvalue $-\lambda$, or $w\neq 0$ and $(T-\lambda \mathrm{Id})(w)=F(v)=0$, in which case $w$ is an eigenvector of $T$ to the eigenvalue $\lambda.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda_i$ the $n$ eigenvalues of $T$ (counted with their multiplicity), so that we have:
$$
Tx_i=\lambda_ix_i
$$
for the eigenvectors $x_i$.

Note that the $n$ eigenvalues of $T^2$ are $\alpha_i=\lambda_i^2$ because:
$$
T^2x_i=T(Tx_i)=T(\lambda_i x_i)=\lambda_i(Tx_i)=\lambda_i^2x_i
$$

so, if $\alpha_i=\lambda^2$ than $\lambda_i= \lambda$ or $\lambda_i= -\lambda$.

Comment: This seems to assume that $T$ has exactly $n$ eigenvalues, but this need not hold for e.g. a non-algebraically closed ground field. Also, It is not clear to me that the multiplicities are all compatible: if $T$ has eigenvalues $a$ and $-a$ with multiplicities $p$ and $q$, is it clear that the multiplicity of $a^2$ as an eigenvalue of $T^2$ is no less than $p+q$?